# Help proving $odd(m^2+n^2) \implies odd((m+n)^2)$

Tags: proof-writing, predicate-logic

I need some help proving the following poposition:

$\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}\;\text{odd}(m^2+n^2) \implies \text{odd}((m+n)^2)$

Since $\text{odd}$ can be defined as:

$\text{odd}(x): \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\; x = 2k+1$

I can write the above statement as:

$\exists k_1 \in \mathbb{Z} \; m^2-n^2 = 2k_1+1 \implies \exists k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\; (m+n)^2=2k_2+1$

After I get to this, I'm totally stuck. To prove this, I think I need to somehow write that $m^2-n^2$ can be written in the form $2k+1$, but using $(m+n)^2$. Is this the write thinking? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Hint: $(m+n)^2 - (m^2+n^2) = ...$

Comment: Your reasoning is correct but it won't take you anywhere because it does not relate in any way the two quantities $m^2+n^2$ and $(m+n)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- Even + Odd = Odd
- $2n$ is always Even
- $(n+m)^2=n^2+m^2+2(nm)$

Comment: So since I know that $(n+m)^2$ is odd then I can say that it's equal to Odd + 2(nm) which you say is even, so it's odd+even which is thus odd?

Comment: @grimrader I thought your hypothesis was $m^2+n^2$ odd

Comment: @Evariste is right: you start with $m^2+n^2$ being odd, and you obtain that $(m+n)^2$ is odd. Although actually the two are equivalent, so both directions work ;)

Answer (score 2):

$(m+n)^2=m^2+n^2+2mn\equiv m^2+n^2 \pmod 2$

So $m^2+n^2$ odd implies $(m+n)^2$ odd.

Comment: How did you use (mod 2) to get rid of the 2mn?

Comment: @grimrader Well $2$ divides $2mn$. So by definition $2mn\equiv 0 \pmod 2$. If you have never met congruence relations then just go with boon's answer, it has the same meaning and might sound more natural.